# javascript alert is firing continously even after clicking OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textbox` where I want a user to add integer numbers and the number of digits should not be less than `10`.

The issue here is that the `alert` message is continuously firing even after clicking OK. Please suggest what is wrong with the code. Also suggest if there any other good methods to implement this

```js
function checkLength(el) {
  if (el.value.length != 10 || el.getAttribute('data-should-alert') === 'false') {
    alert("Minimum 10 numbers are accepted");
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'false');
    el.focus();
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'true');
  }
}

function IsNumeric4(e) {
  var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
  var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
  document.getElementById("error4").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
  return ret;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Stores / Sites  Asst. Manager Mob</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStoreSiteAsstMangrMob" maxlength="10" onblur="checkLength(this)" onkeypress="return IsNumeric4(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
  <span id="error4" style="color: Red; display: none">* Only numbers allowed (0 - 9)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is because the `alert()` takes the focus away from the `input`, so the `blur` event is repeatedly fired in a loop. Solution, never use `alert()`. Show a message in HTML instead.

Comment: This is happens because you are validating filed on blur event, so whenever you click on ok button it will again fire blur event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: how and where to show the message.?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra: any other event to use on ?? let me know

Comment: if you want to test it this way, then its better to use `console.log` rather than using `alert`

Comment: As I mentioned, show the message in HTML, exactly as you do already with the 'only numbers allowed' notification

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Is it possible to write that function inside `IsNumeric(e)`  ?

Comment: Sure, but that's not really going to work as a solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: ohh, then what is the solution sir.. as I am not able to get the exact one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: any help sir ??

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the event **onblur** always fired when the element loses focus

so one solution is to change that event to **onchange** event  instead of **onblur**

```js
function checkLength(el) {
  if (el.value.length != 10 || el.getAttribute('data-should-alert') === 'false') {
    alert("Minimum 10 numbers are accepted");
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'false');
    el.focus();
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'true');
  }
}

function IsNumeric4(e) {
  var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
  var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
  document.getElementById("error4").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
  return ret;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Stores / Sites  Asst. Manager Mob</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStoreSiteAsstMangrMob" maxlength="10" onchange="checkLength(this)" onkeypress="return IsNumeric4(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
  <span id="error4" style="color: Red; display: none">* Only numbers allowed (0 - 9)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: let me try and check.. thanks for quick solution mate!

Comment: but this can't trigger alert again

Comment: alert will be triggered when user click anywhere else

Comment: @BNN How about call focus and clean up the value? that would make it work

Comment: @BNN You could find a way you would like to use.

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to refactor your code and instead of using **window.alert** you can display alert message below the input and display it while the user type the input using **oninput** event

Comment: @mostafatourad: ok.. how should I display it ? can you update your code if you dont mind

Comment: I will refactor all of your code for you , can you give me the value of specialKeys ?

Comment: the value of specialKeys variable

Comment: is this what you want https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173807/discussion-between-bnn-and-mostafa-tourad).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are focusing after the alert is shown

Answer (score 0):

Because alert will trigger blur again.

`setTimeout` gives you a tricky way to make `.focus()` call after `alert`:

```js
function checkLength(el) {
// this may cause once alert, it will always alert
  if (el.value.length != 10/* || el.getAttribute('data-should-alert') === 'false'*/) {
    alert("Minimum 10 numbers are accepted");
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'false');
    // set this
    setTimeout(function(){
      el.focus();
    }, 10);
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'true');
  }
}

function IsNumeric4(e) {
  var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
  var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
  document.getElementById("error4").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
  return ret;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Stores / Sites  Asst. Manager Mob</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStoreSiteAsstMangrMob" maxlength="10" onblur="checkLength(this)" onkeypress="return IsNumeric4(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
  <span id="error4" style="color: Red; display: none">* Only numbers allowed (0 - 9)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what changes you made in this ?

Comment: Yes, take a try. If there's better way, please use and tell me that because this way is really tricky.

Comment: cause your condition's always true though.

Comment: OK, I've modified. Please take a look at that. You should make the condition your way.

Comment: after comment that part of condition, the continuously alert doesn,t show again

Comment: Would you please test the current version of my answer code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173810/discussion-between-bnn-and-terry-wei).

Comment: i guess i already tried your code, did u changed anything in this ?